# i2c mistake: ‘i2c_smbus_read_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, i2c

I use Raspberry Pi 3 Zero, put the sudo apt-get install libi2c-dev package, compile g ++ (Raspbian 8.3.0-6 + rpi1) 8.3.0 Why am I getting these errors?

Command:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c HX.cpp
g++ main.o HX.o -lm -li2c -pthread -lpigpio -lrt -lwiringPi
```

```
    HX.cpp: In constructor ‘HX::HX(int32_t)’:
    HX.cpp:34:17: error: ‘i2c_smbus_read_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope
    int8_t power = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    HX.cpp:34:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘i2c_smbus_ioctl_data’
    int8_t power = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   i2c_smbus_ioctl_data
    HX.cpp:35:2: error: ‘i2c_smbus_write_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1, ~(1 << 6) & power);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    HX.cpp:35:2: note: suggested alternative: ‘i2c_smbus_ioctl_data’
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1, ~(1 << 6) & power);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    i2c_smbus_ioctl_data
```

HX.cpp

```
#include "HX.hpp"
HX::HX(int32_t id){
    device_id = id;
    if(device_id < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error number: %d\nString error: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(ioctl(device_id, I2C_SLAVE, MPU_ADDRESS) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error number: %d\nString error: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int8_t power = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(device_id, MPU_POWER1, ~(1 << 6) & power);

    fprintf(stdout, "%sMPU9250 initialize successful\n", KGRN);
}

HX::~HX(){
    close(device_id);
}
```

Comment: What does `HX.hpp` contain?

Comment: HX.hpp contain is: `
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <locale.h> 
`

Comment: I included linux/i2c.h and linux/i2c-dev.h. But the compiler says "error: ‘i2c_smbus_read_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 2):

I included few headers in HX.cpp, but I used `extern "C"`

```
extern "C" {
    #include <linux/i2c.h>
    #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
    #include <i2c/smbus.h>
}
```

It's working)

Comment: But, why should i use `extern "C"` ?

Comment: They are C headers and you need to mark them as such to use in C++.